# on iOS 10 jailbreak environment，use dlopen system/library/framework error

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering

￼[System processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tin1x.jpg)

System processes:/System/Library/Frameworks/HealthKit.framework/healthd,I dlopen this,appear dlerror:
**dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/HealthKit.framework/healthd,1):no suitable image found. Did find: /System/Library/Frameworks/HealthKit.framework/healthd: out of address space**
I don't know what to do，Can anyone give me some information？

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to dlopen an mach-o executable instead of a dylib, and while dyld (the Darwin dynamic linker) doesn't necessarily mind, the way executable segments are laid out is different, namely you have `__PAGEZERO` which dyld would try to allocate space for and fail. Even if you did manage to dlopen it successfully, you would not be able to do much with it as it not have exported symbols that you could `dlsym`.

If you're trying to load the HealthKit framework, you should load the framework binary itself instead, although it's not necessary since on production builds of iPhoneOS you can use `dlsym` to get any symbol from any of the frameworks from the dyld shared cache, which would usually contain all the system frameworks/libraries.